# Track where visitor came from using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, google-analytics

I want to find a way to track where a visitor has come from. Almost like a mini-Google Analytics. I've got a widget people put on their site, and i want to find out if the users have come from for example, google a direct hit, a referring link, etc.

How would i accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `document.referrer` function to return where the user came from.